# how to override and use the parent class method in child classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop

I have class hierarchy like below picture and there is one non abstract method defined in the class A (suppose) and decedent classes(D,E,F,G,H,I) are calling the same method.

These classes are in api so I can not make changes into them but I want override the myMethod which is defined in Class A and also want Class D,E,F,G,H,I should call new overridden method. I am using spring 4. Can I do this changes whihout overriding the all decedents class and I dont have any option to change the D,E,F,G,.... I am using java 8, spring 4.

```
       A (non abstract myMethod)A is Abstract class
      /   \
    B       C 
    /\      / \ \ \
   D  E    F  G H I
```

Comment: Is the method you are talking about marked final ?

Comment: No, its not final method.

Comment: Its not very clear if you have an option to make changes to D,E,F ... . Can you clarify if you have ?

Comment: No I dont have any option to make any changes in D,E,F,...

Comment: And why not overriding the method in `B` and `C` ? Is it not desirable ?

Comment: @davidxxx no its not desirable and we dont have access to these classes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you already have a dependency on spring, you can use spring-aop to do this. Here are the steps :

- Declare an Around point-cut for your method myMethod()
- Write whatever logic you want for the overridden method.
- Do not call "joinPoint.proceed();"